# Using Geom_Bar in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to use geom_bar in ggplot2, and all of the cases that I see of people demonstrating it online are of comparative frequencies of certain things. The chart that I'm trying to do is the stacked bar graph like this one [image: stacked bars]

However, I want to do it from a vector of values. That is, let's say I have the vector

```
v=c(1,2,3,4)
```

Instead of 4 even bars, which is what I understand I would get, I'd like a stack of 4 bars where the top one is 1 unit tall, and the next one down is 2 units tall (etc.). Is this possible in R?

Edit: Here is the code that I've used for my graph. It's yielding a normal bar graph, not the stacked version that I'm looking for:

```
ggplot(data = v, aes(x = factor(x), y = y)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(y)),stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: what did you try till now? it will be easier to help you with some sample data and code

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet, because everything I've found through googling around (bar chart r yielded the tutorial that I got the picture from) has used frequency of factors grouped by factor names as the example. I haven't used ggplot that extensively, so I'm not sure what the limitations are, or how to format data for it yet.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `stat="identity"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can start from this:

```
v=data.frame(x="My Stacked Bar", y=c(1,2,3,4))

ggplot(data = v, aes(x = factor(x), y = y))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(y)), stat="identity")
```

Comment: What does the 'x=factor(x)' represent?

Comment: I'm telling `R` to consider x not as a value (in this case a text string that could be compared with other strings) but as a category of my data (in this case the only category, so the graph will have only one stacked bar)

Comment: @mucio I see. However, when I ran the code using my data, I got the unstacked bars. Same syntax. Does it not work with too many different data points?

Comment: can you add your code to your original question? is your data `v` a data frame?

Comment: Yes, it's a data frame. I added my code in above. The x represents the column name for the x value, and so on.

Comment: and `x`  is the same for the `y` values that you want to stack together?

Comment: Does x have to be the same? Is that what causes it to stack? If that's so, can I add a third variable to fill by?

Comment: yes, you are telling ggplot to use the column `x` of your dataframe to position values on the `x` axis. If you have another variable that you can use there go ahead.

Comment: @mucio Thanks for your help! One last question. How can I change the legend?

Comment: You can start from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) and then ask a new question about the legend :)