# Plotting a factor column against two columns in one bar plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a bar plot using ggplot where one column is a factor of 0/1 and the other two columns represent count

my dataset looks as follows:

```
id    in      out
0   30036   547148      
1   213176  23902
```

I managed plotting id against in and out separately but cant figure out how to merge both plots together so that 0 has two bars (in/out) representing the counts and the same for 1

Comment: Can you better explain or perhaps draw a picture of what you want? It's hard to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @cardinal40 basically I want one bar plot where 0 and 1 are on the x axis and there's two bar plots for each. and the y axis represents the count of either in or out. For example 0 will have a bar representing in (30036) and a bar representing (547148). The same for 1. Does it help explain it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929845/using-geom-bar-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = T,
  text = "id    in      out
`0`   30036   547148      
`1`  213176  23902")

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  gather(direction, value, -id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(id, value, fill = direction)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]